# Why does code copied from JSFiddle throw the error "$ is not a function" ("Dollar is not a function")?

Tags: javascript

This javascript code is getting an error in browser consoles:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
> at window.call1 ((index):309)
> at SVGGElement.onclick ((index):535)

But [it runs in JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FunkeXMix/pw1e2j3h/4/)

Do you see what's wrong?

```js
var count = 1;
window.call1 = function() {
  const button = $("#icon1 path");
  console.log(count);
  count = count % 2 + 1;
  switch (count) {
    case 1:
      button.css("fill", "white");
      break;
    case 2:
      button.css("fill", "yellow");
      break;
    case 3:
      button.css("fill", "white");
      break;
  }
}

window.call1();
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't done anything to define a `$` function which is most popularly used to assign the jQuery library to but occasionally has other values.

The site you copied the code from loads the jQuery library. See [the jQuery website](https://jquery.com/) to get the latest version of it.

Consider rewriting the code to [not use the library](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/); most of its advantages have been mitigated by improvements in the native APIs provided by browsers.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try to do as you said